# Tying. Is Tieing really that unusual?

Tags: american-english, orthography

When tieing two things together, e.g:

> Two distinct ideas, but with a common theme tieing them together
>
> Tieing shoe laces is easy.

I have always spelt it with an ie. Now I am being told by Microsoft Word that my spelling is incorrect and should use a y. Google seems to largely agree with Word... one of the top hits is this forum thread:

[tieing instead of tying](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tieing-instead-of-tying.3294609/)

which in summary, is the same question as I am, but without the bias I have. The answers all seem to suggest that everyone thinks the ie spelling is valid but weird.

I thought I would ask the experts...

- Is there any distinction?
- Is it possible that the ie is a UK spelling and y is US?

Comment: Ngram does find uses of "tieing", peaking around 1950.  Looking at the "hits", one gets the impression that the spelling is used mostly in special cases -- packaging, mechanics, etc.

Comment: This [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tying%2Ctieing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctieing%3B%2Cc0) plotting the frequency of occurrence of "tying" (blue line) versus "tieing" (red line) for 1800–2008 suggests that _tying_ is far more common. The difference between the [results for the British English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tying%2Ctieing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctieing%3B%2Cc0) ...

Comment: ...and the [results for the American corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tying%2Ctieing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctieing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctieing%3B%2Cc0) appears to be negligible.

Comment: didn't know about that corpus tool, its great... thanks! okay, so basically it's true... I'm spelling it wrong.

Comment: SEE ALSO *die > dying, lie > lying, vie > vying*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no entry in the Oxford English dictionary for tieing in American or British English.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/spellcheck/english/?q=tieing
Although tieing does (as shown in the Ngram graph cited by Sven Yargs above) exist as a rare alternative spelling it is not recognized by dictionaries. In the oxford dictionary's entry for tying there is no mention of the alternative "tieing".